# OpenSSL CSR generation with subject key from stdin

Tags: openssl

Is it possible to pass in the subject's key from *stdin* when creating CSRs with OpenSSL?

Like in the following (non-working)

```
openssl req -new -key stdin -subj '/C=US/ST=NY/L=Somewhere/organizationName=MyOrg/OU=MyDept/CN=fqdn.of.my.host'
```

The

```
-key stdin
```

part is not working.

I want to use OpenSSL for CSR and certificate creating in a scripting environment, and both keys and subject information are coming from a database.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*nix commands usually use a dash to represent stdin or stdout in the context of file parameters, so `-key -` is supposed to read the key from stdin. However, it seems that `openssl` doesn't implement this. Luckily, in Linux pretty much everything is a file, including stdin which can be accessed as `/dev/stdin` (which is actually a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/0`), so the following works:

```
openssl req -new -key /dev/stdin
```

Comment: neat! just tested: works also on FreeBSD.

Comment: Neat.  I have solved this in the past using Unix Named Pipes, but just using /dev/stdin is a good solution.